# How can I set an attribute to a tag when publishing with Orgmode?

Tags: css, org-mode, xhtml

When publishing with orgmode, is it possible to add attributes to generated html tags, only on wanted elements.

For example, I would like to add some class value for tags without this attribute, or replace it (add a class value after the *outline-text-2* one).

```
<div id="text-1" class="outline-text-2">
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Another content</p>
</div>
```

I've searched for this issue into the documentation, but don't find relevant help. It is possible to generate inline *style* attributes, but it's not possible for me to use inline style :)